# Rscript on ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, rscript

Where can I install Rscript from? I need to run an R script from a php file using exec. However I need to install Rscript first.

Comment: Did you know that the StackExchange has it's own forums specifically for Ubuntu?  It's true, and I find them really helpful: askubuntu.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search the ubuntu [repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/).  Have you checked the `littler` package?

Answer (score 19):

The main package for R is called [`r-base`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=r-base). For the scripting and command-line front-end see [`littler`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=littler) (or [`r-cran-littler`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=r-cran-littler) in xenial (16.04LTS) and beyond):

```
sudo apt-get install littler
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think I understand why it happened to you after reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/21841167/1168342

Answer (score 2):

The answers posted so far are generally useful, but they don't directly answer the question. I recently had the same question and discovered there is no rscript binary for Ubuntu. The r binary itself is used to execute scripts in batch mode as opposed to the separate rscript binary that I was using in OS X.

It appears you may be able to get an rscript binary from other sources (see http://craig-russell.co.uk/2012/05/08/install-r-on-ubuntu.html#.UwKWzkJdW2Q for example), but I'm not sure why you would need that when simple running "r script.r" from the command line works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I tried running `Rscript` in a fresh ubuntu installation (16.04.2 LTS) and got:

> `The program 'Rscript' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
>   sudo apt install r-base-core`

so, naturally, i ran `sudo apt install r-base-core`.

installation took a couple of minutes.

Later, i needed to install an R package, and realized i needed an R shell for that. running `r` returned:

> `The program 'r' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
>   sudo apt install r-cran-littler`

Again, i followed, this time it was quite faster.

I don't know if these are the correct steps to take (or why they would be wrong), but it's what the system led me to do.

Comment: This is a late comment, but the right way to run an R shell is with upper-case "R", which should be installed with `r-base`.