# R scripting and command-line front-end

Tags: r, ubuntu-12.04, frontend

I am writing a R script to run the commands in the front-end in ubuntu:

```
Rscript my_scripts.R  my_file.txt output_file
```

However, it gave me an error like "Error: unexpected symbol in "Rscript my_scripts.R"

I came upon this post [R command line passing a filename to script in arguments (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808169/r-command-line-passing-a-filename-to-script-in-arguments-windows). and I quote the answers `"As I said in my comment, I would use Rscript instead of R CMD BATCH:"`

So I found that in order to run this, I have to install

> sudo apt-get install littler

according to this post [Rscript on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022761/rscript-on-ubuntu/8022810#8022810)

When I finished install this package, it still showed the same error message. Any solutions?

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you really running that from the unix shell prompt? Because I can get something like that error by typing that command at the R prompt:

```
$ R
  [startup noises]
> Rscript foo.r
Error: unexpected symbol in "Rscript foo.r"
```

Otherwise its something in your script that is similarly screwed up.

When run from the Unix command prompt, all is well:

```
$ Rscript test.R
[1] 1.414214
```

where `test.R` is simply `print(sqrt(2))`

Comment: errr, my stupid mistake, I did run that in the R console rather than the ubuntu console. Thanks a lot!